# Deleting rows in a range where cell has specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete any rows in the range "Y3:Y50" where in column "Y", the value is "0".

```vb
Dim aRange As Range, aRow As Range, aCell As Range

Set aRange = Range("Y3:Y50")
For Each aRow In aRange.Rows

    For Each aCell In aRow.Cells
        If aCell.Value = "0" Then
            aRow.EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next aCell

Next aRow
```

It is deleting some but not all the rows it should.

The alternative is to delete rows where there is no data in column "A". I feel that would probably be a cleaner option in case I have a row where 0 is the correct value in the future.

Full macro below.

```vb
Sub SubbyRunsheet()

    Dim rng As Range, URng As Range, cel As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Runsheet")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Clean up SOR sheet
    Sheets("SOR").Activate

    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        With Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter 1, "<>" & Worksheets("Runsheet").Range("E1")
        
            On Error Resume Next
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
            
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    
    End With

    'Clean up the runsheet
    Sheets("Runsheet").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Delete
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
    Cells.WrapText = False
    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
     
    'VBasic's code    
    Const Addr As String = "Y3:Y50"
    Const Criteria As Variant = 0
    Set rng = ws.Range(Addr)
    
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If cel.Value = Criteria Then GoSub collectCells
    Next cel
    
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Hidden = True 
    
    Exit Sub
    
collectCells:
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then
        Set URng = Union(URng, cel)
    Else
        Set URng = cel
    End If
    Return
    
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    Cells.WrapText = True
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:Y100").RowHeight = 15

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Reference").Delete
    Worksheets("Format Helper").Delete
    Worksheets("Airtable Upload").Delete
    Worksheets("Formula Sheet").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    WeekEnding = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value, "yyyymmdd")
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C&I Subcontractor Weekly Runsheet - " & Worksheets("Runsheet").Range("D1") & " WE " & WeekEnding
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: When deleting rows it's easier to work from the bottom up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Delete Rows With Criteria

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteRowsY()

    ' Constants
    Const Addr As String = "Y3:Y50"
    Const Criteria As Variant = 0
    
    ' If this is happening in the workbook containing this code,
    ' then use 'Set wb = ThisWorkbook' instead.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' The worksheet is better defined by its name,
    ' e.g. Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    ' Define Column Range.
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range(Addr)
    
    ' Loop through each cell in Column Range.
    Dim cel As Range, URng As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If cel.Value = Criteria Then GoSub collectCells
    Next cel

    ' Test with hiding, you cannot undo the deletion.
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ' When ready, outcomment the previous and uncomment the following line.
    'If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Delete
    
Exit Sub

collectCells:
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then
        Set URng = Union(URng, cel)
    Else
        Set URng = cel
    End If
    Return

End Sub

Sub deleteRowsA()

    ' Constants
    Const FirstRow As Long = 3
    Const tgtCol As Variant = "A" ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    Const Criteria As Variant = Empty
    
    ' If this is happening in the workbook containing this code,
    ' then use 'Set wb = ThisWorkbook' instead.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' The worksheet is better defined by its name,
    ' e.g. Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    ' Define Column Range.
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, tgtCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, tgtCol), ws.Cells(LastRow, tgtCol))
    
    ' Loop through each cell in Column Range.
    Dim cel As Range, URng As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If cel.Value = Criteria Then GoSub collectCells
    Next cel

    ' Test with hiding, you cannot undo the deletion.
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ' When ready, outcomment the previous and uncomment the following line.
    'If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Delete
    
Exit Sub

collectCells:
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then
        Set URng = Union(URng, cel)
    Else
        Set URng = cel
    End If
    Return

End Sub
```

### EDIT:

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteY(Sheet As Worksheet, RangeAddress As String, Criteria As Variant)

    ' Define Column Range.
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheet.Range(RangeAddress)
    
    ' Loop through each cell in Column Range.
    Dim cel As Range, URng As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If cel.Value = Criteria Then GoSub collectCells
    Next cel

    ' Test with hiding, you cannot undo the deletion.
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ' When ready, outcomment the previous and uncomment the following line.
    'If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Delete
    
Exit Sub

collectCells:
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then
        Set URng = Union(URng, cel)
    Else
        Set URng = cel
    End If
    Return

End Sub

Sub delY()
    
    ' Constants
    Const ColumnAddress As String = "Y3:Y50"
    Const Criteria As Variant = 0

    ' Define worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    deleteY ws, ColumnAddress, Criteria
        
End Sub

Sub deleteA(Sheet As Worksheet, _
            FirstRow As Long, _
            ColumnID As Variant, _
            Criteria As Variant)

    ' Define Column Range.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, ColumnID).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, ColumnID), _
                       ws.Cells(LastRow, ColumnID))
    
    ' Loop through each cell in Column Range.
    Dim cel As Range, URng As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If cel.Value = Criteria Then GoSub collectCells
    Next cel

    ' Test with hiding, you cannot undo the deletion.
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ' When ready, outcomment the previous and uncomment the following line.
    'If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Delete
    
Exit Sub

collectCells:
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then
        Set URng = Union(URng, cel)
    Else
        Set URng = cel
    End If
    Return

End Sub

Sub delA()
    
    ' Constants
    Const FirstRow As Long = 3
    Const ColumnID As Variant = "A" ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    Const Criteria As Variant = Empty

    ' Define worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    deleteA ws, FirstRow, ColumnID, Criteria
        
End Sub
```

### Your Final Solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub SubbyRunsheet()

    Const RangeAddress As String = "Y3:Y50"
    Const Criteria As Variant = 0
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Runsheet")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Clean up SOR
    Sheets("SOR").Activate
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter 1, "<>" & Worksheets("Runsheet").Range("E1")
                On Error Resume Next
                .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
            
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    
    'Clean up Runsheet
    ws.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Delete
        ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
        Cells.WrapText = False
        Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    ' Delete rows containing 0-s in Y-column of Runsheet
    deleteY ws, RangeAddress, Criteria
    
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    Cells.WrapText = True
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:Y100").RowHeight = 15
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets("Reference").Delete
        Worksheets("Format Helper").Delete
        Worksheets("Airtable Upload").Delete
        Worksheets("Formula Sheet").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    WeekEnding = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value, "yyyymmdd")
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C&I Subcontractor Weekly Runsheet - " _
      & ws.Range("D1") & " WE " & WeekEnding
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub deleteY(Sheet As Worksheet, RangeAddress As String, Criteria As Variant)

    ' Define Column Range.
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheet.Range(RangeAddress)
    
    ' Loop through each cell in Column Range.
    Dim cel As Range, URng As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If cel.Value = Criteria Then GoSub collectCells
    Next cel

    ' Test with hiding, you cannot undo the deletion.
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ' When ready, outcomment the previous and uncomment the following line.
    'If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Delete
    
Exit Sub

collectCells:
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then
        Set URng = Union(URng, cel)
    Else
        Set URng = cel
    End If
    Return

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi VBasic, thank you for helping out with another of my excel queries! Is there a way to have it so that I can contain this within another macro? At the moment it runs until the end of the code that you've written for me but I have further code that I would like to run afterwards. Cheers!

Comment: @Treeko11: I've added your second case. Could you be more specific about what your doing in your current code and explain how you want to call this code.

Comment: I've added my full macro to my original post, I am basically cleaning up data from a template and formatting it to be presentable. I do this for a large number of sheets each week so I am trying to automate it all.

Comment: You're a legend, thank you again for all your assistance.